# Running (brew) openldap on osx El Capitan?

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, openldap

As Apple keeps making "improvements" to the LDAP that comes with OSX (i.e. keeps breaking it on each update), I had to do my own installation of openldap, which worked fine on Maverick and Yosemite (openldap 2.4.39). However, when I tried to launch it again today (upgraded to El Capitan 10.11.5 a while back) it did not want to start up again. Google searches suggested to upgrade brew and reinstall:

```
%> brew update && brew upgrade
%> brew reinstall homebrew/dupes/openldap --with-berkeley-db
```

After this, I had a fresh openldap 2.4.43 installation. Unfortunately that did not do the trick. openldap now stops again right after launching:

```
575fdffe /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 53 (database  bdb)
Unrecognized database type (bdb)
575fdffe /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 53: <database> failed init (bdb)
575fdffe slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
575fdffe slapd stopped.
```

Googling for this showed tips that one needs to uncomment some lines in the config. In slapd.conf I can see the following config:

```
# Load dynamic backend modules:
# modulepath    /usr/local/Cellar/openldap/2.4.43/libexec/openldap
# moduleload    back_bdb.la
# moduleload    back_hdb.la
# moduleload    back_ldap.la
```

However, the referenced folder does not exist. Any ideas anyone? Oh... and answers in "complete idiot" style would be appreciated as I know way to little about sys admin in general and specifically ldap. I'm "just" a developer. THANKS!

Comment: You break out of the box with the osx, would be easier to run a vm to test out setting

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that the "--with-berkley-db" tag is not valid anymore. The current command is:

```
brew reinstall openldap --with-berkeley-db@4
```